# htaccess rule for getting and setting the parameter after the domain name

Tags: .htaccess

How can I write the htaccess rule for the below scenario:

Here is my domain: http://localhost/xyz/ : it is converting to http://localhost/xyz/#/ while hitting the url. My application is in angular js.

Currently, If I am entering http://localhost/xyz/dinesh/ which is not permissible and produce "404". I wish to allow the user pass his username in the url, and want to access the username in the whole application. here 
'dinesh' is the username.

If http://localhost/xyz/dinesh/ entered, should be converted to http://localhost/xyz/

Plz help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ /? [R=301,NC,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^xyz/([a-zA-Z]+)/$ xyz/?username=$1 [QSA]
```

This will only accept alphabetical characters for the username, and convert it to a parameter `username`. Any existing query string will be preserved. Let me know if that needs tweaking.

Comment: No need to escape `/` in `^xyz/([a-zA-Z]+)/$` pattern?

Comment: No, no need to escape them. That only applies when it is the delimiter, as it is in a number of languages, but not in mod_rewite. Patterns are just delimited by space at each end or quotes if preferred.